# Google in-app updates api not updating latest version of app from play store

Tags: android

I have implemented google In-app updates in my android project. There are two ways of implementing the in-app update.
1. Immediate and 2 Flexible.

I am using Flexible mode to update the app.

Now There is 1.0.7 version of my app exist in google play store which is updated one.I have retained version 1.0.3 in my app for testing purpose. Mean while There are five versions like 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6 and last 1.0.7 (which is latest version).

When I create signed apk and then it show alert to update the app in flexible mode, when I go for the update, after updating I restart the app and then it shows version 1.0.5 not the latest version which is on playstore (1.0.7).

Can anyone please tell me why it's not updating latest version(1.0.7).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having the same problem!

Comment: I reported this issue to Google if anyone found solution Please comment here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140952855

Comment: have you found any solution?